# WindowManager and RecycleView ignoring ItemList params

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, android-windowmanager

I'm having an odd behavior while using RecycleView and WindowManager (TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT). For some reason attributes of the ItemList (padding, width, heigh, ...) are being ignored. I have no idea about what is going on. I would like to check with you guys is I'm missing something or doing something wrong.

Inflating List on WindowManager:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

paramsMap = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                PixelFormat.OPAQUE);

final RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(getApplicationContext());

recyclerView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(list));
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
wm.addView(recyclerView, paramsMap);
```

Item Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lincensePlace"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It suppoused to be inflated like that:
[image: Correct behavior]

But that is what I'm getting:
  [image: Wrong behavior]

Comment: Had you find this solution?

Comment: I've ended up using a different approach for the app. Never figured out what was happening there.